# Localization in enterprise application

Tags: c#, mvvm, prism, enterprise

where would you place "localization & globalization" in an enterprise application 3-layered builded in c# WPF with MVVM and Prism? I mean in an application built like the pattern describe in msdn (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee658124.aspx) in which layer would you put the logic for localization? what kind of approach would you use (resx files, db...)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resx files

but this is NOT a trivial subject and there isn't any one standard approach, with the major ones being:

1. using WPF Resources
2. using wpf's Locbaml tooling
3. using RESX files as xaml static strings
4. using RESX files with an extension

Recommended references: [Sacha Barber](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37339/WPF-Localization), [Josh Smith](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31837/Creating-an-Internationalized-Wizard-in-WPF), and [ResX](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35159/WPF-Localization-Using-RESX-Files).

My preference is to use a combination of (3) and (4), although I needed to modify the code for the extension a bit. So I will typically have

1. A project (MyApp.Presentation.Resources) of Resx file(s), one per view
2. A project (MyApp.Domain.Resources) of Resx file(s), one per enum type, standard commands
3. A project of view models (MyApp.ViewModels) which references MyApp.Domain.Resources enums as needed
4. A project of controls and/views) (MyApp.Wpf.ControlLib) which references MyApp.Presentation.Resources and my version of a ResxExtension.dll.

HTH,
Berryl

Answer (score 1):

I have used `resx` files for this in an enterprise application. They were placed in their own `Resources` project so they could be shared across multiple user interfaces.

It is worth reading up on how Microsoft intended this to work as it uncovers some compelling reasons to do things this way:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6zyy3s9%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use DB localization mapping. This way no need to recompile application after every localization changes.